# Suspend a running Coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I can suspend a coroutine by calling `suspendCoroutine<String> { cont -> continuation = cont }` inside a coroutine but how do i suspend it from outside of coroutine and get a continuation back to resume it later?

**Edit:**

The job of coroutine is to receive json messages from server using jackson streaming api and store them using sqlite and also notify activities of new message if callbacks are not null (activities are running)

Now when the service (which holds coroutine) is already running and updating database, if an activity connects to it, i want activity to first fetch all the messages from database and then continue receiving new messages from service.

**Problem:**

- If i let coroutine run while activity is synchronizing messages from database, new messages might not be synchronized fully/properly or end up in the middle of old messages, reason i want coroutine to be paused until synchronization is completed.
- I cannot check if i should suspendCoroutine **before** jackson starts waiting for new message, it will quickly pass this condition.
- I cannot check if i should suspendCoroutine **while** jackson is waiting for new messages from network (blocked on read), it cannot be done.
- I cannot check if i should suspendCoroutine **after** jackson has received a message because then I will have to wait for a new message to start synchronization.

**Edit2:**

I think best solution is to just start synchronization and add a check if activity is already synchronizing  **after data is received and before any callbacks are made or data is stored to database**, that way, coroutine can freely block on read and not insert new data until activity is finished synchronizing.

Comment: There is no way to do that. A coroutine can suspend only on the _suspension points_ defined precisely by calling `suspendCoroutine`. Clearly you can't inject that code from the outside, to any arbitrary place.

Comment: So i must use external bools to check if coroutine should suspend itself or not! Very sad.

Comment: "very sad" you're probably trying to do something weird

Comment: @TimCastelijns Question edited

Comment: If you could arbitrarily suspend a coroutine at any point, you'd get the exact same semantics as `Thread.suspend()` --- an idea so bad that they actually _never_ implemented it. This is why the only sane way to implement this is with an explicit check at a point where it's safe to suspend. I think in your case you should suspend before receiving another JSON message, and after you have already saved the previous message to the local db.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are opening two different coroutines instead of one, which gives you 0 control to which one runs first:

You could just do all the work inside one coroutine and the execution of it would be as imperative programming is:

```
someScope.launch(someDispatcher){
  val dataFromDb = fethDbData()
  if(dataFromDb.size == expectedSizeOrSomething){
     //start api call
     val apiResponse = response.fetchNetworkData()
     if (response.isSuccessful){
       parsePerhaps()
       insertNewDataToDatabase()
      }
   }
}
```

That should be it, by the description you make.

Comment: There is only one coroutine running which receives new data while app is in background and saves data to database but same is responsible for updating activity ui via callbacks, if there is no activity (app is in background) everything is fine but when activity starts, it will have to synchronize all the data from database including the new one from coroutine in correct order

Comment: Problem is that while activity is synchronizing data, there might be a few new messages inserted by the coroutine which might not get synchronized by activity because eg it started synchronization when there were 8 messages in database but when it finished, database had 10 messages, so activity is short of two messages

Comment: then just require data from the same source, not two of them